# Fusion Tables API and google Maps Advanced Visualization

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

are there other files that I need to add so as to create a good visualization using Fusion Tables API and Google Maps API because i have done exactly as shown in the example  provided by google but its not showing the chart neither is it performing the queries also..

[Fusion tables and Google Maps API Example from Google](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/adv_fusiontables)

Comment: The sample-code is working fine for me when I copy it, the only thing you'll need to change is the path of the stylesheet from `/apis/fusiontables/docs/samples/style/default.css` to `https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/style/default.css`  (otherwise it can't be found on your server)

Comment: I thought that css is already in the example?